# Printing Linked List prints only the head node

Tags: c++, linked-list

After randomly filling a linked list with a deck of 52 cards. When I try to print it, it will print the head node 52 times. Is there something wrong with my 'traverse through linked list logic' or something wrong with my insertion logic?

These are the Node helper methods (a `bagNode` has a `CardOfBag` and a next)

```
card *bagNode::getCard() // retreives card in the bagnode as pointer
{
  return this->cardOfBag;
}
bagNode *bagNode::getNext() // retreives the next bagnode as pointer
{
  return this->next;
}
void bagNode::setCard(card *card) // sets card of bagnode
{
  this->cardOfBag = card;
}
void bagNode::setNext(bagNode *setNode) // sets next bagnode
{
  setNode->next = this->next;
  this->next = setNode;
}
```

These are the methods for the linked list (called `bag`):
it has a header, tail, and current `bagNode*` pointers.

```
void bag::add(bagNode *node) // adds node to random position
{
  int i, place, size;
  place = randomPosition();
  size = getCurrentSize();
  if (size == 0) // for initial insertion into empty linked list
  {
    setHead(node);
    setTail(node);
    alterSize(1);
  } else {
    if ((size - 1) == place) // if the insertion is at the last node
    {
      this->tail->setNext(node);
      setTail(node);
      alterSize(1);
    } else {
      if (place == 0) // if insertion is at head node
      {
        node->setNext(this->head);
        setHead(node);
        alterSize(1);
      } else {
        setCurrent(place); // for any insertion in between first and last nodes
        node->setNext(current->getNext());
        current->setNext(node);
        alterSize(1);
      }
    }
  }
}

int bag::getCurrentSize() // returns size of bag (linked list)
{
  return this->size;
}
void bag::alterSize(int num) // changes the size int of bag by num
{
  this->size = this->size + num;
}
int bag::randomPosition() // generates random number from 0 to size exclusive
{
  int size = getCurrentSize();
  if (size != 0)
    return (rand() % size);
}
void bag::setCurrent(int desiredPosition) // this traverses the current pointer
                                          // by desiredPosition steps from the head node
{
  int i;
  this->current = this->head;
  for (i = 0; i < desiredPosition; i++) {
    this->current->setNext(this->current->getNext());
  }
}
bagNode *bag::getCurrentNode() // returns node of current pointer
{
  return this->current;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that, just fixed it

Comment: `setCurrent` modifies the list in a strange way.  Have you stepped through this in a debugger?

Comment: I've tried using gdb but I am not sure how to use it fully. What should I be looking for? The setCurrent() function is used by many other functions and it does not cause the program to throw any errors.

Comment: Although not related to the question, if `rand()` may return a negative number, then `rand()%size` may be negative.

Comment: Does `this->current` ever change?

Comment: How to use the debugger: Build a list of expectations for the state of the program after every line of code you wish to debug. Place a break point at the beginning of the code to be debugged. Run the program and let it stop at the breakpoint. Step the program line by line. Make sure the state of the program matches the expectations. If it doesn't, You've either found a bug in the program or an error in your expectations. Either one needs to be corrected.

Comment: In `setCurrent` you wish to traverse a list until `current` reaches the `desiredPosition`th `bagNode`. When you step over `this->current->setNext(this->current->getNext());`, does `this->current` now point to the next node? If not, you need to find out why.

Comment: With regards to using the gdb, sometimes when I use the step command, it will execute entire loops or functions. Is there a way for me to slow it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bagNode::setNext() is supposed to make next point to the node provided; leave the other node alone:

```
void bagNode::setNext(bagNode* setNode) //sets next bagnode                                                                              
{                                                                                                                                        
  this->next = setNode;
}
```

Your bag::setCurrent() doesn't work. You're supposed to make this->current keep going "next" until you hit the desiredPosition, instead you're only changing its next pointer to... **the same value it previously had**.

Do something like this instead:

```
void bag::setCurrent(int desiredPosition)                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                        
  int i;                                                                                                                                 
  this->current = this->head;                                                                                                            
  for(i = 0; i < desiredPosition; i++)                                                                                                   
    {                                                                                                                                    
      this->current = this->current->getNext();
    }                                                                                                                                    
}
```

That should work better now.

Comment: @rcgldr not entirely sure what you mean, doesn't the setter change the value of next? ah, gotcha (after your edit). Yeah, editing my answer.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you! But, I still don't really understand why this->current->setNext(this->current->getNext()); doesn't work?

Comment: setNext(node) sets the .next pointer. getNext() gets the current .next pointer. So your code would read as "set my .next pointer to my current .next pointer"

Comment: ohh wow, i feel like in idoit... I can't believe I didn't see that, thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

in your function

```
void bag::setCurrent(int desiredPosition)
```

You are not changing *this->current* at all. Basically you did nothing in that function.

Comment: You can strengthen this answer by 1)  explaining WHY nothing was done and 2)  suggesting a solution to the problem.